# The HTTP Post always hit in my controller even for loading the view only

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller with two methods in it for adding requests but the HTTP POST method always hits while debugging even for loading the view only . Besides i also have a HTTP GET method also .

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddRequest()
{ 
return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddRequest(Request Obj )
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
// Do something
}
else
{
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error");
}
return View();
}
```

Now when i run my page it always hit the second method instead of the first one . i am using kendo UI Grid as well . Does it has something to do with it ?

Comment: show the calling code in the view

Comment: Html.BeginForm("AddRequest", "RequestBackUp", FormMethod.Post, new { 
    AutoComplete = "off" })     Its simply on form submit call .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i got the solution . i was using a kendo UI grid in my view and that also had an Ajax call in it which was causing a problem by hitting the POST method at the same time . Do watch Out for that .

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
```

i commented this ajax part and all was fine and go .

Answer (score 0):

Check your request method in headers for GET or POST. 
When you run your application, page request normally goes as GET and your [HttpGet] action will be hitting.